# How to MPI Send and Recv Nested struct with Pointer Array of Struct?

Tags: c, mpi, hpc

Here are the struct declaration and code below:

```
struct cell_struct {
    int x, y;
    bool isWater, isPort, isRock;
    struct port_struct port_data;
    struct ship_struct *ships_data[MAX_SHIPS_PER_CELL];
    int number_ships;
};

struct ship_struct {
    int route, totalHoursAtSea, hoursAtSeaThisJourney, id, numberPassengers, euclideanPlannedDistance;
    bool willMoveThisTimestep;
};

// Data associated with each port
struct port_struct {
    int shipsInPastHundredHours[10];
    int port_index, passengersShipped;
    double totalFeesCollected;
};

struct cell_struct *domain_test;

domain_test = (struct cell_struct *) malloc(
            sizeof(struct cell_struct) * (mpi_info->local_size_x + 2) * simulation_configuration->size_y);
```

Using the following Send and Recv, I was able to send and receive, domain_test, but was not able to access ships_data from domain_test after sending and receiving.  Any help in this?

```
MPI_Send(&domain_test[mpi_info->local_size_x_end * simulation_configuration->size_y + i], sizeof(struct cell_struct), MPI_BYTE, 1, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Recv(&domain_test[0],sizeof(struct cell_struct) * simulation_configuration->size_y, MPI_BYTE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Comment: There is no easy way. One option is to create a derived datatype so you can send/receive in one shot but this is a bit tedious. An other option is to "inline" the `ships_data` (e.g. declare `struct ship_struct ships_data[MAX_SHIPS_PER_CELL];`). Yet an other option is to send `ships_data` one at a time. Last but not least, you can use a temporary buffer and `MPI_Pack()`/`MPI_Unpack()` your data so you can send/receive the buffer in one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that the `cell_struct` stores a static array of *pointers to ships*, which means the data of the ships itself may be all over the place. If you instead store a static array of ships, [as suggested by Gilles in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70588684/how-to-mpi-send-and-recv-nested-struct-with-pointer-array-of-struct/70723711#comment124793140_70588684), you have a contiguous chunk of memory that needs to be sent. You can even send it using `count=sizeof(cell_struct)` and `type=MPI_BYTE` then (like you do now), or any of the methods indicated by @Gilles.

The consequence for your code is that the ships are now copied when assigned to a cell, rather than just setting a pointer. This is not a problem if the ships have little data, as shown here, but if copying is expensive, it may make the code slower.

Answer (score 0):

For the transfer of complex data structures between systems, this is where some form of serialisation comes into play, if you don't wish to arrange the structure(s) as one contiguous lump of memory as suggested by Jonas.

With the C programming language, to use a serialisation technology you're pretty much stuck with schema-first, e.g something like Google Protocol Buffers (see [C version](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c) and [Google's page](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)). Other languages like Java and C# have serialisation built in, so they give you a choice of code-first or schema-first serialisation.

The briefest of overviews is:

1. Write a schema files (.proto for GPB) that describes your data structures, much as you would do with struct{} definitions in C
2. Compile the schema with the provided tool(s) to output C code that does define your data structures using struct{}, plus a set of functions that can serialise / deserialise them to / from a wireformat
3. Use that generated C code in your project. You use the generated structures to declare variables as required, and use the serialise / deserialise functions to generate / consume MPI_BYTE buffers,
4. You send / receive these MPI_BYTE buffers using MPI

There are some fundamental advantages to this:

- Your distributed system can be heterogenous. So instead of having to have, for example, 64-bit C running on a PC running Windows 10 64-bit compiled with the same compiler everywhere, you can mix and match languages, machine types, OSes, compilers, etc;
- You can have data structures laid out as makes sense, rather than making them a bit more obscure for the sake of achieving storage in contiguous memory.

My guess is that if you're re-arranging memory to build / deconstruct contiguous memory for the sake of sending / receiving data, you'd be better off (from a run-time length point of view) with a serialisation technology like GPB.